# Plesk, server reboot, php-fpm module not auto starting

Tags: php, nginx, plesk, reboot, autostart

This morning I noticed my Plesk VPS had restarted.

All websites were offline because the '`PHP-FPM support for nginx`' service did not start on boot.
I don't see an option anywhere in the Plesk UI to enable the auto-start of the service. How can I make sure that the service auto starts in the future?

```
OS  CentOS 6.7 (Final)
Plesk version   12.0.18 Update #64, last updated at Sept 13, 2015 04:23 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to start it with the following command

```
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

To start PHP-FPM on boot:

```
chkconfig --add php-fpm
chkconfig --levels 235 php-fpm on
```